# Ruby Read File And Convert It To An Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, find

I want to read this text file:

```
Almanya,Berlin
Andorra,Andorra La Vella
Arnavutluk,Tiran
Avusturya,Viyana
Belarus,Minsk
```

and convert it to an array like this:

```
country = ["Almanya","Berlin","Andorra","Andorra La Vella"...]
```

So I thought, I could easily get and read the country name and the code could return the capital name. Maybe this solution would be a bad one but I don't know.

I tried like this:

```
File.open('login.txt') do |f|
     f.lines.each do |line|
       userarr << line.split.map(&:to_s)
     end
end
```

But the result was:

```
[["Almanya,Berlin"], ["Andorra,Andorra", "La", "Vella"],...]
```

How can I do it in ruby simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)

This one-liner will do what you want, returning a flattened array. You can certainly break it up into multiple method calls for debugging or readability, but it works as posted.

```
File.readlines('/tmp/corpus').map(&:chomp).flat_map { |line| line.split ?, }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
userarr << line.split.map(&:to_s)
```

to

```
userarr << line.split(',')
```

You need to split on the comma, not on the space.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read the file into a string and split on commas and newlines:

```
File.read("my_file").split(/,|\n/)
  #=> ["Almanya", "Berlin", "Andorra", Andorra La Vella", "Arnavutluk",
  #    "Tiran", "Avusturya", "Viyana", "Belarus", "Minsk"]
```

To eliminate any leading or trailing spaces, tack on `.map(&:strip)` or change the regex to `/\s*,\s*|\s*\n\s*/`.

If the file is large, you can read it a line at a time:

```
File.foreach("my_file").flat_map { |s| s.split(/\s*,\s*|\s*\n\s*/) }
  #=>["Almanya", "Berlin", "Andorra", "Andorra La Vella", "Arnavutluk",
  #   "Tiran", "Avusturya", "Viyana", "Belarus", "Minsk"]
```